# Nothing happens when I call web3.eth.sendTransaction

Tags: web3js, metamask, dapps, ropsten, alchemy

I am very new to web3, I am trying to use metamask with alchemy web3 wrapper.
Metamask is connected and I can get account address and account balance but when I try "transaction" function, literally nothing happens, no response or error. I have tried both metamask's window.ethereum.request function and web3's web3.eth.sendTransaction function.
I am using ropsten.

Comment: What code are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it after a few days, crypto is ban in Pakistan so I had to use a proxy.